# JQuery Duplicate Email Validation

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, validation

I have just started studying programming and I've been stuck for hours in this problem. I have a sign up form which asks for email and it should check the mysql database if the email is already registered. I am currently trying to use the remote method from the Jquery validator plugin but I can't seem to make it work.

**emailcheck.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$email = $_POST['CusEadd'];
$query = "SELECT CusEadd FROM customer WHERE CusEadd='$email'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count>0){
    echo json_encode(FALSE);
}
else {
    echo json_encode(TRUE);
}

?>
```

**form-validation.js**

```
CusEadd: {  
            required:true,
            email:true,
            remote:"emailcheck.php"
        }
```

Comment: If you're using the jQuery validate plugin, I believe it makes a GET request by default, you'd have to specify POST if that's what you want

Comment: Especially if you're just starting to learn programming please **don't use PHP's `mysql_*` functions**. They were deprecated in PHP 5.5, which is so old that it no longer receives security updates, and completely removed in PHP 7. Instead, use PDO or `mysqli_*`.

Comment: Yeah. I would definitely stop using mysql and learn how to use PDO. thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/#remote-options) for jQuery Validate states that

> The serverside resource is called via jQuery.ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and
>   gets a key/value pair corresponding to the name of the validated
>   element and its value as a ***GET*** parameter.
>
> The serverside response must
>   be a JSON string that must be "true" for valid elements, and can be
>   "false", undefined, or null for invalid elements

You're checking for `$_POST['CusEadd']`, and assuming you have an element with that name, you still have to specify POST as a method

```
CusEadd: {  
    required:true,
    email:true,
    remote: {
        url  : "emailcheck.php",
        type : "POST"
    }
}
```

Also, you want to return the string  "true", not PHP booleans, which usually converts to numbers

```
if($count>0){
    echo json_encode("false");
}
else {
    echo json_encode("true");
}
```

And do not use `mysql_*` in production code, your code is open to SQL attacks by simply passing something like `'OR 1=1` to the POST variable

Comment: Thank you!! Thank you very much! You are a real life saver. And also I'm gonna remove the mysql and use mysqli instead. thank you again!!